# Express router.post not executing block, but found

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In my index.js file, each form action called executes properly:

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var async = require('async');
var common = require('./common.js');
var log = require('./log.js');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/premise', function...

router.post('/follow', function...
```

views/index.jade

```
extends layout

block js
  script(src='/javascripts/countdown.js')
  script(src='/javascripts/table_filter.js')

block content
  if username...

         ...div.followers.table_wrapper
              h3.table_header.center Following
              #followers_tbl.center
                h4.center You are not following anyone...
                form(action="follow" method="post")
                  input(type="text" name="follow_username" id="follow_username" placeholder="Add username here...")
                  button(class="btn btn-primary btn-sml" type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 15px") Follow A User
          div#add_premise.textarea_wrapper
            form(action="premise" name="premise" method="post")
              textarea(name="premise" id="premise" placeholder="Enter your..." required)
              p.countdown.black
              button(class="btn btn-success" type="submit") Add Premise
```

But when I call from another page /signup it doesn't work. (See below EDIT file details).

The call returns a 302, so it is found, but the function doesn't execute. But when I remove `action='signup/signup/'` from the form in the view, then change the `router.post('/signup', function...` to `router.post('/', function...`, the function executes, after also returning a 302 in my log.

Can anyone help me? Thanks so much!

EDIT: (Adding app.js and more of routes/signup.js)

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var fileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

var index = require('./routes/index.js');
var signup = require('./routes/signup.js');
var login = require('./routes/login.js');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var session_options = {
  name: 'server-session-cookie-id',
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store: new fileStore(),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 // 1 year
  }
};

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session( session_options ));

app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
  try {
    if ( ( req.session && req.session.username ) ||
      req.originalUrl == "/login" ||
      req.originalUrl == "/signup" {
      next();
    }
    else {
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
  }
  catch( err ) {
    common.send_500( req, res, err );
  }
});

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/signup', signup);
app.use('/login', login);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie(session_options.name);
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  catch( err ) {
    common.send_500( req, res, err );
  }
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

routes/signup.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var encrypt = require('./encrypt.js');
var common = require('./common.js');
var log = require('./log.js');

/* GET signup page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    var signup_error = req.session.signup_error;
    req.session.signup_error = null;
    res.render('signup', { title: 'Signup', signup_error: signup_error });
  }
  catch( err ) {
    common.send_500( req, res, err );
  }
});

router.post('/normal', function(req, res, next) {...});

router.post('/submit', function(req, res, next) {...});

module.exports = router;
```

views/signup.jade

```
extends layout

block js
  script(src='/javascripts/dob_validate.js')

block content     
              div#signup_form
                  form(action="/signup/normal" name="signup" method="post")
                    input(type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus)
                    input(type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required)
                    input(type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password" required)
                    input(type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required)
                    p#dob
                      | Birthdate
                      input(type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" style="margin-left=20px;" required).pull-right
                    label
                      input(style="margin-right: 5px;" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" required).pull-left
                      | Check here to indicate that you have read, understand and agree to the
                      a(href="/terms")  Terms of Use,
                      a(href="/privacy")  Privacy Policy
                      |  and
                      a(href="/cookies")  Cookie Policy
                      | .
                    div#signup_btns
                      button(class="btn btn-primary" type="submit") Sign Up
                      a(href='/login') Login
```

/signup/normal/ handler:

```
router.post('/normal', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username.toUpperCase();
    var password1 = req.body.password1;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;
    var birthdate = req.body.birthdate;

    birthdate = birthdate.substring(5,7) + '/' +
      birthdate.substring(8,10) + '/' +
      birthdate.substring(0,4);

    if (password1 === password2) {
      var body = JSON.stringify({
        "username"      : username,
        "password_hash" : encrypt.hash(password1),
        "credits"       : 100,
        "email_address" : email,
        "birthdate"     : birthdate
      });

      var path = "/accounts/add/";

      common.post( path, body, function( data ) {
        try {
          if ( data && !data.error ) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data.resp));
            res.redirect('/login');
          }
          else {
            req.session.signup_error = data.resp;
            req.session.save( function(err) {
              res.redirect('/signup');
            });
          }
        }
        catch( err ) {
          common.send_500( req, res, err );
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      req.session.signup_error = "Passwords do not match";
      req.session.save( function(err) {
        res.redirect('/signup');
      });
    }
  }
  catch( err ) {
    common.send_500( req, res, err );
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create separate route js files for each route instead of defining all your routes inside the main index.js?

Comment: Only index ("/") and signup ("/signup") are defined in my app.js file. "/follow" is not defined in app.js, but is in my index.js as a post and works.

Comment: what happens if you comment out all the session logic and all the redirect logic so that its just requests to /signup/normal are not encumbered by any if statements or redirects?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal because your are using `signup.js` router with `/signup` end point:

```
const signup = require('./routes/signup.js')
...
app.use('/signup', signup)
```

Assuming that you define a route handler inside `signup.js` to `/about` route:

```
router.post('/about', function(req, res, next) { ... });
```

Then the app will be able to handle requests to `/signup/about`. If you create a route handler for `/signup` then the end point is `/signup/signup`

I suggest you to change the `/signup` route to `/user` like this: `app.use('/user', signup)` and also change the form action to `action="/user/signup"` this makes more sense

Comment: That's exactly how I'm structured.  But my router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {...}); doesn't execute the function for my request to "/signup/signup"... But if I delete the action="signup/signup" and make it router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {...}); for a call of just "/signup/" that same function executes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `action="/signup/signup"`, note the `/` before the first `signup`

Comment: Tried that just now... Same problem.

Comment: the post handler should be like this: `router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {...});`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... And I did that, and the it's found and logs a 302, then the code doesn't execute. I'm so confused.

Comment: Http 302  means a redirect response, it seems that you are sending redirect response from your server, show the code inside route handler

Comment: I have updated the question with an EDIT that includes more of the files including app.js, routes/signup.js, and views.signup.jade

Comment: this is confusing, you said that you are posting form to `/signup/signup` now in the edited question I see `action="/signup/normal"`, you have to show me the post handler, by this I mean: `router.post('/normal', function(req, res, next) {...});` because it returns 302 result, we have to know why it returns such a result

Comment: Very sorry. I changed that to make it less confusing.

Comment: it's normal if you get 302 response because you are sending redirect response in all cases, if the passwords don't match you redirect the page to `/signup`, if no error redirect to `/login` else redirect to `/signup` again, So where is the problem then ?

Comment: The problem is when I hit this post, the common.post API function doesn't execute... But if I change the code in the view and route to make that exact same function the only post request, it executes without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixup here between GET requests and POST requests, and which is on what endpoint.

If you're hitting `localhost:3000/signup`, then that endpoint should be returning your `signup.jade` file (by the way this is a server-side html rendering you're using....).  You're serving dynamically generated HTML content at that endpoint.

However, By typing in `localhost:3000/signup` within your browser address bar, you're executing an HTTP **GET** request, not a **POST**.  Very important difference here!

Thus, you now need a router endpoint of `router.post('/signup/signup', function...)` to actually catch the form submit (note this is now a POST) from your jade template. Honestly I would want to point out your naming scheme here, because as you can see `/signup/signup` is quite confusing and doesn't follow a very good convention.

Comment: I have a router.post endpoint. I log "POST /signup/signup 302 17.491 ms - 56 -" but no function execution.

Comment: Then I change the router.post under signup.js from accepting '/signup' to '/' and log "POST /signup 302 42.649 ms - 56" with the function executing.

Comment: I've tried router.post('/signup'... & router.post('signup/signup'... both give me the some log with no function execution.